# Replacing concern Special Characters with underscore ("_") from word document in java

Tags: java

My requirement is to replace the concern special characters with the underscore("_") from word document and write it into new word document. The following code is replacing the special characters on the textual content. But it is not working if the document (.doc) contains the text with images. Kindly let me know if you have any solution  on this requirement?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {    File file = null;
        WordExtractor extractor = null;
        try
        {  
            file = new File("C:/Users/DSAL454/Desktop/Audit final.doc");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            FileOutputStream os = new  FileOutputStream("C:/Users/DSAL454/Desktop/Audit fin.doc");
            HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fis);
            extractor = new WordExtractor(document);

            System.out.println("total length ");
            String[] fileData = extractor.getParagraphText();
            for (int i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++)
            {
                if (fileData[i] != null)
                    System.out.println(fileData[i]);
                String str1=fileData[i].replaceAll("[\"#%*:<>?/|]","_");
                String str2=str1.replace("\\","_");
                System.out.println(str2);
                os.write(str2.getBytes());

            }       
        }
        catch (Exception exep)
        {
            exep.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What means "is not working"? Do you get any error message?

Comment: u have to find out what xml tags they use for the pictures and ignore that

Comment: why are you not using POI for the creation of the new word doc?  If you are just writing the paragraph text then I guess you may be missing a lot of stuff.

Comment: Include necessary jar files.CHeck http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...i didnt get any error. My file (Audit final.doc) has both text contents and images. While i was using this code, new word file (Audit fin.doc) was created. But it has only word content not images. I need new word file with text contents (after replacing special character with "_") and images.

Comment: Anyone help me to solve this problem..